# ElasticSearch, return results, dedupped and with custom sort bubbling to top

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I have an index of listings. Each have a weight associated with the document. I need to be able to search for "Engineer", and get the top result back for each match of "title" based on the relevance and arbitrary weight associated to the document.

Sample Index:

```
Doc 1 {"title": "Java Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 2 {"title": "Search Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 3 {"title": "Ruby Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 4 {"title": "PHP Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 5 {"title": "Java Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 6 {"title": "Search Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 100}
Doc 7 {"title": "Java Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 100}
Doc 8 {"title": "MySQL Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
```

The desired outcome if I were searching for "Engineer" would be that it deduplicates the items by same title, and returns the best result within the resultset with a boost of the weighted_importance fields, e.g.:

```
Doc 6 {"title": "Search Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 100}
Doc 7 {"title": "Java Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 100}
Doc 3 {"title": "Ruby Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 4 {"title": "PHP Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
Doc 8 {"title": "MySQL Engineer", "content": "A long description", "weighted_importance": 10}
```

The last three results would be sorted however they fall, but the top two would need to bubble to the surface within their own buckets.

I'm new to ElasticSearch, as you can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: vote it up. This is a good idea. I understand, you'd like to get unique index  on key of `title` with top `weighted_importance`, and sort the output. with the `jq` or other json tool, maybe you can get expect output, but in elasticsearch with GET URL, let see if anyone has idea on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

- your mapping should, also, store a `not_analyzed` version of your `title`, so that the buckets will be built based on the full title, not on individual terms forming the title:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "engineers": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields":{
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "weighted_importance": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- group the results on buckets built on `title.raw` defined above
- define a `top_hits` sub-aggregation to bring back the "best" document for each bucket
- define another sub-aggregation on the same level as the `top_hits` one that should be a `max` aggregation that will compute the maximum `weighted_importance`
- in the main aggregation use the `max` above to sort the resulting buckets

```
GET /my_index/engineers/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "Engineer"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "title": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.raw",
        "order": {"best_hit":"desc"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_match": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{"weighted_importance": {"order": "desc"}}],
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "best_hit": {
          "max": {
            "lang": "groovy", 
            "script": "doc['weighted_importance'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now to get geo_point working in conjunction with the solution.